# C++ Practice Programs

Tags: c++

I am currently learning C++ and now understand things like classes and pointers, etc.

Anyone have an idea of what programs I should practice writing when teaching myself C++?

Comment: Lots of people post `give-me-teh-codez` requests here on Stack Overflow. You could write programs for them...

Answer (score 1):

Try reading books that have exercises at the end of every chapter and try making them.

Answer (score 1):

You can check Thinking in C++. The books are available online and they have exercises at the end of each chapter.